# How to run external executables within firejail

Tags: permissions, executable, sandbox, firejail

My machine is home desktop(personal) running Debian Buster with i3 window manager. I recently installed firejail with `apt install firejail* firetools` and also downloaded the new Firefox 83 browser from Firefox official website. I can run the firefox binary as a non-firejail user, as in, navigating to the new firefox directory and running `[user@debian]:$ ./firefox` It works fine and all. However, if I try doing, `firejail --noprofile --seccomp --private --nonewprivs /home/user/downloads/firefox/firefox` it says, `the file firefox isn't executable`. Running ls -l on the executable returns that it is executable. Then I copied the whole new firefox directory to /tmp/ then opened a new firejail bash session with `firejail --seccomp --private --nonewprivs bash`, then started a sandboxed bash session. Then copied the firefox directory from /tmp/ to $HOME and tried running the firefox binary from there, and it says `permission denied` The file was executable, and was owned by same user. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to run a 32bit firefox on your 64bit system or vice versa? I've tried your command and it works here, however Firefox cannot open any websites. You'll definitely need to use firefox.profile or something similar.

Comment: I've managed to run the new firefox 83 in firejail issuing `firejail --secccomp --noprofile --apparmor --caps.drop=all --x11=xorg --private --nonewprivs` before that, I copied the firefox directory to /tmp and started it from there. Copying the diriectory back to home inside firejail made it non-execuatble again. Now only way for me to run it is to copy the directory to tmp. What commands did you issue? Were you able to run new firefox directly from the directory without copying the direcoty over to anywhere else

Comment: The Firefox release from Mozilla is what I've been using since the late 90s, only it was called Netscape Navigator back then. I have it installed in `/opt/firefox` and it starts from there just fine under `firejail`, albeit it cannot open websites. Haven't tried any other directories.

Answer (score 0):

The firejail documentation states:

> Use –private Firejail option to start with a factory default browser
> configuration, and an empty home directory.

So running  `firejail --private  bash`    then  `ls ~` should show empty. Are you sure it said "the file firefox isnt' executable" at that point?

I am trying to do the exact same thing as you. The two options I can see are:

1. Modify/make a custom  `/etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile` which calls a modified `disable-exec.inc` which doesn't include the line: `noexec ${HOME}`

or

2. Put the firefox83 directory in `/opt/` and run it from there.

The first option reduces security and may be overwritten by a new firefox install.

I went with the second option.

If there is a way to exempt a directory from the later noexec instruction that would be ideal... anyone?